# How to convert all columns to Text, while using TextToColumns, by default it was in General format - Using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-automation

I need to split texts using delimiter `|`.But after split its truncating front zeros:

**Input**

```
0001|00030455|testing
0003|00004532|testing
```

**Expected Output**

```
0001  00030455  testing
0003  00004532  testing
```

**Getting Output like this**

```
1  30455  testing
3  4532   testing
```

**Tried this**

```
$colA=$wst.range("A1").EntireColumn
$colrange=$wst.range("A1")
$colA.texttocolumns($colrange,1,-4142,$false,$false,$false,$false,$false,$true,"|",@(1,3))
```

[Option in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNhAv.png)
How to use above option in TextToColumn() using powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Range.TextToColumns documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.TextToColumns) it looks like your `@(1,3)` is where the column types should go, and that's saying the first column should be a date in MDY date format, which doesn't look right.

Instead, I think that should be:

```
@((1,2),(2,2),(3,2))

# so

$colA.TextToColumns($colRange,1,-4142,$false,$false,$false,$false,$false, $true,"|",@((1,2),(2,2),(3,2)))
```

Which is column 1 type 2 (xlTextFormat), column 2 type 2, column 3 type 2.

That seems to work for me in a quick test:

[image: Excel spreadsheet showing the output with leading zeros]

Comment: @DineshKumar You're welcome :)   (Please upvote or click the 'accept answer' tick if it's helpful)

Comment: Is that any possible ways to give that in a single shot, because i have more than 300 columns. Did i need to do like this @((1,2)(2,2),........(300,2)) or any other easy ways.

Comment: @DineshKumar I don't know if it will work, but you could try to generate that first as `[array]$formats = 1..300 | foreach-object { ,@($_, 2) }` and then use `$formats` in the call to `TextToColumns`.